# Switching @Query to nativeQuery causes PropertyReferenceException

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data

I'm using Spring JPA with Hibernate & PostgreSQL.

I have the following JPA repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.UUID;

public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, UUID> {
    @Query(value = "Select * From event Where ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_MakePoint(:swLongitude, :swLatitude), ST_MakePoint(:neLongitude, :neLatitude)), 4326), location)", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Event> qwerty(@Param("swLatitude") double swLatitude, @Param("swLongitude") double swLongitude, @Param("neLatitude") double neLatitude, @Param("neLongitude") double neLongitude, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Back when the query was HQL and didn't have `nativeQuery` set as `true` it worked fine. Now I need to move to a native SQL query, and though adding `nativeQuery = true` and rewriting the query would solve it.

However, I now get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property qwerty found for type Event!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:213)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:321)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:301)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:82)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:60)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:91)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:168)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:69)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:320)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:169)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
... 34 more
```

Obviously, it used to not be called `qwerty`; I just renamed it to illustrate this better.

It seems to ignore the `@Query` annotation somehow, and that it is the annotation which should define the query to execute, and tries to interpret it based on the method name instead.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taken from the documentation of Spring Data JPA (version 1.6.0.RELEASE):

> The @Query annotation allows to execute native queries by setting the
>   nativeQuery flag to true. Note, that we currently don't support
>   execution of pagination or dynamic sorting for native queries as we'd
>   have to manipulate the actual query declared and we cannot do this
>   reliably for native SQL.

It is evident that native queries will not work with pagination.

So if you absolutely need native query support you will have to drop pagination, or you'll have to right a custom repository implementation in which you will implement that feature on your own

Comment: Thanks for the quick and correct response, I should have been reading more carefully. The error message could have been more user-friendly though.

Comment: @geoand FYI We created https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-554 to create a more sane exception message in cases like this.